# How to convert new SomeFunction() syntax to TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

When attempting to convert a simple JS file to TS with implicit "any" disabled, I get this error:

> error TS7009: 'new' expression, which lacks a constructor signature,
>   implicitly has an 'any' type.

```
interface Logger {
    new ():any;
    //():any; // "Callable" syntax. same error.
    //new ():LoggerInstance; //Same error.
}
interface LoggerInstance {
}

function Logger(): void {
}


var defaultLogger: LoggerInstance = new Logger();//error TS7009
//var defaultLogger: LoggerInstance = <any>new Logger();//same error
//var defaultLogger: LoggerInstance = <LoggerInstance >new Logger();//same error
```

I don't see how to do this without converting the Logger function into a class.

Without implicit any disabled, the typescript compiler was making any suggestions for improvement, so I'd like to leave that setting on.

**Update**: If I remove "new" from the Logger interface and then cast the result of new Logger(...), got it to compile in the full file, but in my smaller test example, I continue to get the same error.

**Update 2** Okay, I think what happen is the error warnings go away when the plugin that red-underlines syntax errors crashes. I'm thinking that this style of object creation must be forbidden when "implicit any" is disabled.

Comment: So why not turn it in to a class?

Comment: When it is a class, it becomes an IIFE returning an object not a "new'd function" I have no idea what impact this would have. If type script compiler requires in the processes of annotation throwing the code away and using entirely different structures, I might as well use CoffeeScript or Python or what have you.

Comment: What is the difference between a new'd function's return and an object? I did not understand your reply to Nypan.

Comment: function Car() {}; car1 = new Car(); is valid ordinary JS, ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new I can't figure out how to use that pattern in TypeScript with "implicity any" disabled, i.e. I can't annotate it in a way to make the compiler happy. Notably, the Car() function doesn't have a return value, but the new operator results in an assignment of an object, not an undefined.

Comment: Did not have time to look at this for a few days, but I finally got around to composing an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The short bad answer**

```js
interface IPerson {
    name: string;
}

var person = function(name: string) : void {
    this.name = name;
}

let funcPerson = <IPerson>(new (<any>(person("John Doe"))));
```

This works and compiles with the noImplicitAny flag.

**The longer better answer**

Just convert it to a class:

```
class person {
    constructor(public name: string) { }
}

let classPerson = person("John Doe");
```

This compiles to:

```
var person = (function () {
    function person(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    return person;
})();
var classPerson = new person("Jane Doe");
```

This is an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), which in the simple case above makes no difference what so ever compared to the `var person = function...` implementation. They are exactly the same thing.

Converting the newable function to a class is only beneficial. It makes the code readable, it is easier to refactor and easier to expand/modify in the future. It also has better type information (you do not even need the interface in this case).

In short I can se no reason for using the newable function version over the class version of this solution. Both versions result in identical objects (refer to `classPerson` and `funcPerson` above).

**A third option**

If you have a working .js file that you want to use with typescript an option is to write a .d.ts file. In that case you can do something like this:

*person.js*

```
var person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

*person.d.ts*

```
interface PersonStatic {
    name:string;
    new(name: string) : PersonStatic;
}
declare var person: PersonStatic;
```

When you use this you would be able to do:

```
/// <reference path="your.d.ts"/>
var p = new person("Jane Doe");
```

and it would work.

In that case the person.js file has to be present at run time for the javascript to execute properly. 
The .d.ts file above is a basic example, if you decide to go down this road i recommend reading up on creating .d.ts files a bit before charging ahead.

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense. I can see why I couldn't stumble on the syntax for <IPerson>(new (<any>(person("John Doe"))));

Comment: the `new (<any>(person...` breaks for me, apparently due to the extra bracket which is kept in the generated JS `new (person`, the `this` is `undefined` inside the `person` call. TS 2.1.4.

Comment: Yes, just to clarify the (<any>(person... syntax breaks the runtime javascript - it does for me too with (...) is not a constructor

Answer (score 3):

> Define the type and type's constructor structures. Interfaces would work just fine.

```
type PersonType = {
    name: string;
    greet: (otherPerson: PersonType) => string;
    selfIntroduce: () => string;
}

//ordinary functions are called with or without the "new" operator and
//the constructor's type must indicate both signatures

type PersonTypeConstructor = {
    (this: PersonType, name: string): void; //<- "this" could be omitted here
    new(name: string): PersonType; // <- "this" must not appear here
}
```

> Define the function that will be used as the constructor. ***this*** must be specified as the first parameter(since TS 2.0) so the compiler will not  complain when the *noImplicitThis* flag is set true.

```
const Person = (function Person(this: PersonType, name: string) { 
    this.name = name;
}) as PersonTypeConstructor; // <- cast the constructor here so no other cast will be necessary.

Person.prototype.greet = function (otherPerson: PersonType) {
    return `Hello, ${otherPerson.name}!`;
};

Person.prototype.selfIntroduce = function () {
    return `Hello, my name is ${this.name}.`;
};

let peggySue = new Person("Peggy Sue");
let maryAnn  = new Person("Mary Ann");

console.log(maryAnn.selfIntroduce());
console.log(peggySue.greet(maryAnn));
```