# 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

We have the following `TestComponent.ts` TypeScript class:

```
01: import TestVectorLayer from './TestVectorLayer'
02: 
03: export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
04:   private foo: any;
05: 
06:   constructor() { }
07: 
08:   const layer = new TestVectorLayer("foo");
09: }
```

And the following `TestVectorLayer.ts` function:

Keep in mind that OpenLayer's 3 is using the Google Closure Library, that's why `TestVectorLayer` is not a TypeScript class.

```
01: declare let ol: any;
02:
03: const TestVectorLayer = function (layerName: string) {
04:   ...
05:   console.log(layerName);
06:
07:   ol.layer.Image.call(this, opts);
08: }
09:
10: ol.inherits(TestVectorLayer as any, ol.layer.Image as any);
11:
12: export default TestVectorLayer;
```

We're getting the following error:

```
Error on Line 08 in TestComponent.ts class:
```

> [ts] 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.
>       import TestVectorLayer

The `package.json` versions of TypeScript:

devDependencies:

```
"typescript": "~2.2.1"
```

Comment: Why do you want to `new` this function? I ask because, while there's an easy fix that will suppress the error, it may indicate a simple way in which your design may be improved

Comment: And if you want to `new` it why can't `TestVectorLayer` be a class?

Comment: @Saravana this should not matter, at the end of the day class is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I've updated the question. `TestVectorLayer` is using OpenLayer 3, which is uses Google Closure Library.

Comment: @WilomGfx Agreed. But declaring it as a class makes it easier to get typing benefits from TypeScript. You can declare everything as `any` and won't change a thing in the compiled JS, but you lose the benefits of using TypeScript.

Comment: @fuzz so you are using `--allowJs`? I'm still slightly confused because if it's a third-party library, why are you consuming it's from a relative path instead of from its package with its package.json and license files?

Comment: @Saravana True, would not hurt to make a class indeed. Just for the typing benefits.

Comment: @WilomGfx I'd be happy with an answer as to how to create `TestVectorLayer` as a TypeScript class but ensuring that the Google Closure way of inheritance is kept intact and working. If it works the same way then I'm happy to stick with that moving forward.

Comment: @fuzz I'm becoming increasingly perplexed, you said it was a JavaScript file but I see type annotations in it now... this doesn't have anything to do with Angular or even Webpack by the way

Comment: The question is what does ts give you? If you are thinking of a class, you would expect there will be properties or methods for you to access.
In this case, the compiler has no way to know what will be available.
You can create a `TestVectorLayer` interface with `new()` and the properties and methods available. 
That's when it starts becoming useful.

Comment: There's a variable statement as a member of the class on line 8. That doesn't work.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Okay, so it doesn't have anything to do with Angular or even Webpack.

Comment: Another very convenient and terse answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098999/how-to-convert-new-somefunction-syntax-to-typescript

Answer (score 103, accepted):

David answer is great, but if you care just about quickly making it compile (for example because you are migrating from JS to TS) then you can simply put `any` there to shut up complaining compiler.

TS file:

```
const TestConstructorFunction = function (this: any, a: any, b: any) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
};

let test1 = new (TestConstructorFunction as any)(1, 2);
```

compiles to this JS file:

```
var TestConstructor = function (a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
};
var test1 = new TestConstructor(1, 2);
```

---

Just pay attention to not make this mistake:

TS file:

```
// wrong!
let test2 = new (TestConstructorFunction(1, 2) as any);
```

JS result:

```
// wrong!
var test2 = new (TestConstructor(1, 2));
```

and this is *wrong*. You'll get `TypeError: TestConstructor(...) is not a constructor` error at runtime.

Comment: I'm migrating from very old JS and that would be the right answer in my case.

Comment: thanks a lot,  it works!  `const s1 = new (Student as any)('elite', 23);`

Comment: So this niche answer got more likes than the proper one. This is a little alarming as newcomers could think like it's a normal approach. It's a cheat, which is a little better than `@ts-ignore`.

Comment: @Onkeltem Yeah, surprised me as well that it got more likes. Well, people want to fix compiler error and move on. I can't blame them. I guess it's better than not using Typescript at all ;-) Accepted answer is clearly better because it provide proper type definition for function so is type-checked at all `new FunCtr(...)` calls. But if you only have to fix one place where it's called then I think it's not that big of a deal. IMO using `as any` should be considered as bad practice in general but sometimes you just want to shut up the compiler and move on...

Comment: Honestly, even the accepted answer is cheaty :) I spent two days trying to come up with a good `new` annotation for functions, but... gave up. It's basically not supported well by TypeScript because since ES6 we have now normal `class`es and supposed to use them instead. And using this `new` with functions is an attempt to make ES5 work in TypeScript :)

Answer (score 59):

Here's a simplification of the question:

```
const TestVectorLayer = function(layerName: string) {
};

const layer = new TestVectorLayer("");
```

The error is happening because `TestVectorLayer` doesn't have a new signature, so `layer` is implicitly typed as `any`. That errors with `--noImplicitAny`.

You can fix this by switching to a class, but in your case this seems a bit more complicated because the inheritance is done by the underlying framework. Because of that, you will have to do something a bit more complicated and it's not ideal:

```
interface TestVectorLayer {
  // members of your "class" go here
}

const TestVectorLayer = function (this: TestVectorLayer, layerName: string) {
  // ...
  console.log(layerName);
  ol.layer.Image.call(this, opts);
} as any as { new (layerName: string): TestVectorLayer; };

ol.inherits(TestVectorLayer, ol.layer.Image);

export default TestVectorLayer;
```

Then in the file with `TestComponent`:

```
const layer = new TestVectorLayer(layerName); // no more compile error
```

Comment: Your more complicated but not ideal solution works. :) Thanks for providing a temporary fix. We'll try working towards switching to a class. Originally we switched to a class and found a whole bunch of problems with the inheritance so that's why we went with the hybrid approach of JS and TS annotations.

Comment: @fuzz no problem! There might be a better way... just can't think of one at the moment.

Comment: @DavidSherret can you please share where can i get more info/docs about `as any as`

Comment: @SohelAhmedM read about type assertions [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html). `as any` is a type assertion to the `any` type. Doing `value as any as T` is two type assertions and is a way to assert the type of `value` as `T` when the type of `value` cannot be asserted as `T` (ex. when `value as T` would cause a compile error, but you want to assert it any way). Essentially, it's a way of bypassing the type checker.

Comment: Gotta love Typescript. How many hours are wasted trying to figure this stuff out?

Comment: ugly but exactly what I needed thanks :) would be great if you could provide a simplification of the answer also

Comment: Yeah, it's ugly. And you had to turn function declaration into function expression.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, You have to define it as `any` and has `new` signature, for example.

```
const dummyCtx = function(txt: string) {
  this.foo = txt
} as any as { new (txt: string): any }

// just use it as usual
const dctx = new dummyCtx('bar')
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures I was reading through the typescript docs and encountered the problem like in the question above. This actually solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I would give your TestVectorLayer an interface

```
class TestVectorLayer implements TestVectorLayer {
    
}

interface TestVectorLayer {
    new (layerName: string): TestVectorLayer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running in a TS environment with `noImplicitThis: true` (either in `tsConfig.json` or by default), you will get this error if using the approach given by @rob_james [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67990975/688448): `'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation`

To fix, add the `this` pseudo-argument to the outer declaration and declare a string-based record object as the return type for the `new` signature, per below:

```
const dummyCtx = function(this: any, txt: string) {
  this.foo = txt
} as any as { new (txt: string): Record<string, any> }

// just use it as usual
const dctx = new dummyCtx('bar')
console.log(JSON.stringify(dctx))
// Will show:
// "{"foo":"bar"}"
```