# How to mark function as newable / how to create a type that expects either a function or a class

Tags: typescript

I have a list of constructors and my application calls `new` on all of them. Those constructors can either be plain functions or ES6 classes. I want to create a type that expects the same argument types from either a class constructor or a plain function.

I tried this:

```
interface Ctor {
  new (st: string, ln: number): any
}

interface CtorList {
  [index: string]: Ctor
}

let list: CtorList = {
  cls: class {
    constructor (st: string, ln: number) {}
  },
  fun: function (st: string, ln: number) {

  }
}
```

But in the definition of `fun`, I get this error:

> Type '(st: string, ln: number) => void' provides no match for the signature 'new (st: string, ln: number): any'.

Check it [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJgPZWQbwLABQyyIEA7sgBQDOYAXMrVKAOYA0yANiAyAK4BbAEbQAlAzggAnoQC+hQqEixEKdFgAywWrkLEA2qAAmEAB4MmrALoN1UOQoKcIYLtvppMULToC8uomQETmoGYLhqagDiYgQMECY+BC8qWgswZhB2Lh4SQREoUVx5QNk2PWQYPlyqkGTgeNSPSyyObl58sQCKktkgA).

So it seems to me like I have two options:

1. Mark the function `fun` as newable
2. Change the type of `Ctor` to also accept plain functions with the same parameters

I'd prefer #2 because I wouldn't want to use type assertions or something similar on each and every function that is defined.

How would I do that?

Comment: 3. Don't use functions when your intention is to construct them rather than call them.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes, but I'm writing a library and I want to support that, as [it's valid JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

Comment: @HristiyanDodov so you are asking how to write types that won't inhibit users who don't make use of the types? You might want to rethink this.

Comment: I just want to make TS accept a plain function where a class is expected. Classes are syntactic sugar and you can use them interchangeably with plain functions in JS. Since TS is a superset of JS, you should be able to do that there as well?

Comment: TS also has the ability to enforce semantically accurate JavaScript where it makes sense. One such example is using `class` to construct, and `function` to call. If you look at the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html), there is not a single place where they exemplify the use of a function as a constructor. Then why would you expect consumers of your library to do so? And while yes, it is valid JavaScript, so are several other concepts that are disallowed in TypeScript for various reasons.

Comment: do you have to call via new? wrap your constructors into factory functions https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGKLAeygT2QbwFgAoZZACgGcwAuZaqUAcwBpkAbEOkAVwFsARtACUdOCBwkAviRKhIsRCgDCWKARJkQEAO4VqdBszadu-IVFHJxk4jOJzw0eEjQZsOADLBqG0sgBtUAATCAAPQzBGECYAXTp0BDVbexIYHhAk4EwQZCxE5PIk7DpVbCsCjz8yKAgwHihc9MywbNyqWnoo4w4uZF5BEWqyZFr6xv7dZGKoDpMQYQBuTWR7VOJ2Oo4fTsrcb18AXmGEdko6fPdcIvY4SkphsgQchh4Z-U6jGPmzQcsCexkKTCFgrZp0ZpZHIfSLRVi9X4WYTDNZAA

Comment: @PatrickRoberts makes sense. So I guess then the answer for my use case is - I shouldn't support this pattern. But to answer the actual SO question - can this be achieved or not?

Comment: @HristiyanDodov `type Ctor = (new (st: string, ln: number) => any) | ((st: string, ln: number) => any);` is this all you asking about? If so it's trivial.

Comment: As @AluanHaddad suggested: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJgPZVRkBnMKAVwUymQG8BYAKGWRAgHdkAKAgLmQKlAHMANMgA2ILiCIBbAEbQAlFzggAnrQC+tMMoAOKdFgCyEMAAsMAE2QBeNp26F+Q0eKmyoc6wD5kS5QG5aWlBIWEQ9MgAZYAJKWnoAbVBzCAAPLh5+AF0ufWxcHhIyZAAfNDIjUwt1QJphYxFosBzIxutYumQEYTwuLrg8PHb6egR8wkKsWyb7XhBBETEGV3lKDQ61ATjkGCJFnZBSYFwp9Ic5p0WJGRXqGi21tSA

Comment: Could someone post it as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: I have the same question about how to mark a `Function` to be a Newable. It seems no one has the solution for this?

Answer (score -2):

I found an answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43624326/1123955 can make this work:

Declare your function by:

```
const fun = function (st: string, ln: number) {}
  as unknown as {
    new (st: string, ln: number): {} 
  }
```