# 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, back

I tried to put this script to increase the security of the system but it gave error with the typescript, in this case, I tried to put it in the app.ts

obs: this code was an attempt to convert a script in nodejs to typescript

script

```
import express from 'express';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import redis from 'redis';
import RateLimit from 'express-rate-limit';
import RateLimitRedis from 'rate-limit-redis';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import routes from './routes';

import ErrorHandler from './app/middlewares/errorHandler';

 class App {
  public server = express();

  constructor() {
    this.middlewares();
    this.routes();
    this.errorHandlers();
  }

  middlewares() {
    this.server.use(express.json());
    this.server.use(helmet());

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      this.server.use(
        new RateLimit({
          store: new RateLimitRedis({
            client: redis.createClient({
              host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
              port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
            }),
          }),
          windowMs: 1000 * 60 * 15,
          max: 100,
        }),
      );
    }
  }
```

region with error

```
new RateLimit({
      store: new RateLimitRedis({
        client: redis.createClient({
          host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
          port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
        }),
      }),
      windowMs: 1000 * 60 * 15,
      max: 100,
    }),
```

message of error

'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the implementation of RateLimit and RateLimitRedis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623461/new-expression-whose-target-lacks-a-construct-signature-in-typescript)

Comment: I couldn't apply it to my code, probably because here we are dealing with a class within another

Answer (score 1):

You should add type descriptions for those packages:

```
npm i @types/express-rate-limit --save-dev
npm i @types/rate-limit-redis --save-dev
```

This goes to all other install packages as well. If you have a package that does not have a corresponding type definitions package then you should create it yourself.

Comment: The dependencies for handling scripts have been installed as a developer

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you change from

```
new RateLimit({
    //...
})
```

to

```
new (RateLimit as any)({
      //...
}),
```

Will fix the issue.