# Is there any way to create object using function in TypeScript , like JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, object, ecmascript-6

I want to create Object using Function in TypeScript like JavaScript.

##### Eg.

```js
function Box(a,b) {
    this.width=a;
    this.height=b;
}
var box=new Box(3,5);
```

I tried this code in TypeScript, It throws me error `'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.` and also `'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.`
[image: Typescript snippet]

I am expecting to create object like using function

```js
var box=new Box(3,5);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623461/new-expression-whose-target-lacks-a-construct-signature-in-typescript)

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes you can, like this:

```
class Box {
    width: number;
    height: number;

    constructor(a: number, b: number) {
        this.width = a;
        this.height = b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible if you use `let Box = function ...` instead of `function Box...` with type casting and interfaces, but there are probably other problems here while manually typing.
It's better to just use `class`es (see the other answers).

For demo purposes:

```
interface BoxStatic {
    new(a: number, b: number): BoxInstance 
}
interface BoxInstance{
    width: number
    height: number
}
let Box = function (this: BoxInstance, a: number, b: number) {
    this.width = a;
    this.height = b;
} as unknown as BoxStatic;

var box: BoxInstance = new Box(3, 5)
```

You can rename `BoxInstance` to just `Box` then it acts somewhat similarly to the typing produced by a `class`.

Comment: Oooh, that double cast is unsightly. It's basically telling the type system "I have *no* idea what this is, but it's *definitely* a `BoxStatic`"

Comment: @MathiasFalkenberg An alternative is `as any as BoxStatic`. But then it's also unsightly and is almost like saying "It can be _anything_, but it's _definitely_ a `BoxStatic`."

Comment: Both approaches sort of defeat the purpose of using Typescript to check your types in the first place...

"Just use classes" is probably the best advice.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is 'No', since Typescript specifically differentiates between objects and functions, which is why it is complaining about your use of the 'new' operator for a function.

As mentioned in another answer, an object in Typescript is created using the `class` operator and giving the class a `constructor`.

Since Typescript is a superset of javascript, your code would technically work, but since you *are* using Typescript, it would make sense to leverage that type system